# Error: Not able to retrieve after create in plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am executing a plugin synchronously postOperation. 
I create an entity using `IOrganizationService.Create`. This works, I get a GUID and I can see that the record exists in the CRM.
Right after this, I am trying to retrieve the same record using same IOrganizationService and the GUID returned by the create call:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ITracingService tracer = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
        tracer.Trace("context is " + context.InputParameters["Target"]);
        context.OutputParameters["Message"] = "in plugin";

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is EntityReference)
        {
/* some other processing here
.
.
*/
 Guid polId = service.Create(policy);
               Entity polEntity = service.Retrieve("new_customEntiry", polId, new ColumnSet(true));
```

But the `polEntity.Id` is null. `polEntity["someattribute"]` is also null .

Why is the retrieve call not working? What am I missing?

Related post: [Error Account with Id = "xxxxxx" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609263/error-account-with-id-xxxxxx-does-not-exist/53106489)

Comment: Can you post `serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService` method body?

Comment: I don’t get it, why do you want to retrieve it from database, whereas you just created it & you have all the data already about the record in policy object. What is going to be extra??

Comment: I agree with @ArunVinoth when you have an object containing Guid and all the other information, you do not need to fetch it again.
Also check here, are you sure you are using correct entity Name??? Before you fetch try to add a check of Guid polId  of Guid.Empty.

`Entity polEntity = service.Retrieve("new_customEntiry", polId, new ColumnSet(true));`

Comment: I want to update a lookup field in some other records with this entity.
Before doing that, I am checking if the guid returned by the create method is null (code is not included in this post). The update call resulted in below error:
Exception details: 
ErrorCode: 0x80040217
Message: new_customEntity With Id = a902fd34-f5dd-e811-a998-000d3a37d203 Does Not Exist

@AnkUser

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM I am using Microsoft.Xrm.sdk libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there are issues in code which you didn't share.

**Possible rootcause**:

The entity used for policy object in `service.Create(policy)` should be same as `new_customEntiry` which used in `service.Retrieve`, check it

**Recommendations**:

1.Add a trace log to log the `polId` in plugin trace or profile/debug it to see
2.Try asynchronous mode & test the same plugin step
3.Don't retrieve the whole entity object, instead do this

```
Guid polId = service.Create(policy);

Entity toUpdate = new Entity("new_entityToUpdate", entityToUpdateId);
toUpdate["new_customEntiryId"] = new EntityReference("new_customEntiry", polId);
service.Update(toUpdate);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Arun! Changing to async worked. 
Wondering what is the difference? Why does retrieve call not work in synchronous mode? I am able to retrieve other entities after the create call.

Comment: @jingle123 could be because the DB transaction is not yet completed but trying to retrieve the record created within the transaction.